# How to properly set id for individual mouseover buttons

Tags: javascript, html, popup, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a column of buttons that have to do the same thing as the first button but with there own individual pics. How do I set the id so that there's no glitches? Right now I have three buttons set up but they somehow copied the same name (they all say mobile quick wash)! Here is what I have so far http://ultimatefinishdetailing.com/Services.html

HTML: (posted HTML BEFORE on the image button)

```
<STYLE MEDIA="screen" TYPE="text/css">
.pop-up {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position:absolute;
right:-50px;
top:75px;
}
.button {
      width:300px;
      height:21px;
      display:block; background-image:url(images/button_ufad4.jpg);
      position:absolute;
}
</style>
<a href="" class="button" onmouseover="javascript:ShowImage('images/InteriorandExteriorDetailing.jpg')" onmouseout="javascript:HideImage()"></a>

<div id="popup" class="pop-up">
   <img id="popupImage" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(src)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
        var div = document.getElementById('popup');
        img.src = src;
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    function HideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! use different id's,classes, for every button. example below is of one button, change numbers of id's/classes for every other button

HTML: 1. the CSS (style)has to have it's own id EX:(.pop-up1,2,3,etc.; .button1,2,3,etc.)
      2. the `<A>` (anchor tag)has to have its own id and class EX:(ID=BUTTON1,2,3,etc;  CLASS=button1,2,3,etc.)
      3. the div tag `<div>` has to have it's own id, class, image id EX:(DIV ID="popup1", CLASS="pop-up1",IMG ID="popupImage1

```
<STYLE MEDIA="screen" TYPE="text/css">
.pop-up1 {height: 100px;width: 100px;margin-right:-100px;margin-top:-100px;position:absolute;display:none;right:-50px;top: 75px;opacity:.7;z-index: 1}
.button1 {
      width:300px;
      height:21px;
      display:block; background-image:url(images/button_ufad4.gif);
      position:absolute;
}
.button1:hover {    background-position:left 43px;
}
</STYLE>
<A ID="BUTTON1" HREF="" CLASS="button1" ONMOUSEOVER="javascript:ShowImage('images/ufad2servicesexteriorandinteriordetailing.gif')" ONMOUSEOUT="javascript:HideImage()"></A>
<DIV ID="popup1" CLASS="pop-up1">
<IMG ID="popupImage1"> 
</DIV>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(src)
    {
        var img= document.getElementById('popupImage1');
        var div= document.getElementById('popup1');
        img.src=src;
        div.style.display="block";
    }
    function HideImage()
    { document.getElementById('popup1').style.display ="none";}
</script>
```